# MVC public ActionResults accessiblity from URL - is it safe?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, c#-4.0, data-annotations

I have being programing in MVC for a couple of months, recently I've been requested to revisit our authorization mechanism.

There is an attribute that checks weather a user can access an action result, but this attribute doesn't appear above all the public actions. There are plenty of JsonResults and other ActionResult actions which can be accessed from the URL bar.

My question is weather its worth adding that attribute to all the action results
or make some sort of attribute that won't allow access to the action unless its an ajax request or a post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no functional difference between a browser request and an ajax request, they both come through the same http pipeline. Matter of a fact, sometimes executed outside of the forms authentication scheme, so adding `[Authorize]` attribute could block valid requests as well.

I would create some sort of authorization that requires the use of a header value of some sort to distinguish access to your Json methods.

You could add the header to every ajax request that was passed, but that would be easily visible in a program such as Fiddler or Firebug. You could use constantly changing authorization keys, but I think the headache of overhead would be at a higher cost than the data you're likely trying to protect.

You could decorate your methods with `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` but again, those can be easily remedied using a program like Fiddler or Postman (chrome add-on)

Comment: The data is quite important, but not likely to be discovered, unless you actually know what are you looking for, most actions take some sort of an ID as a parameter which is pretty long. Is `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` worth adding to those kind of actions? or should I look in to those onstantly changing authorization keys you've mentioned?

Comment: I would say for a majority of users, restricting it to `POST` would be sufficient. If you're concerned about someone "hacking" the system, I would look into a deeper security measure for your ajax methods. Be sure to update any ajax calls to make requests via `POST`, rather than `GET` for any of those that you change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Request.IsAjaxRequest` to ensure that the request came from an AJAX request. This will verify that the `X-Requested-With` header is present in the request, which is not present in a request that is made via the address bar.

What is the threat that are you trying to guard against? Checking the above is good to stop casual users from reading your `JsonResult`s but ultimately you cannot protect public `ActionResult`s or `JsonResult`s because if someone wants to capture your response they can simply make their own request using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

```bash
curl --header "X-Requested-With: XmlHttpRequest" www.example.com/controller/method
```

Comment: Most of our users are casual users without too much knowledge in programming or hacking. The reason why I'm trying to prevent URL bar navigation is because I came across a couple of users using the url bar instead of the menu. I guess if you know what you are doing its faster to navigate that way, for instance you are trying to access some sub action. I haven't looked in too deep in the matter, all I want is that those users won't somehow access an action they aren't suppose to use or see.